# How to create a Barcode code using python and store the png file in s3 without saving in local

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3, barcode

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from io import StringIO # python3; python2: BytesIO
import boto3
import pandas as pd
def generate_asst(request):
    df=pd.DataFrame
    list_of_images = []
    for i in range(10):

        number = 'xxx43256'
        number = number + str(i)
        print(number)
        EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('Code39')
        ean = EAN(number, writer=ImageWriter())
        fullname = str(i) + 'barcodhhe'
#         filename = ean.save(fullname)
        filename = ean.save(fo)
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            contents = f.read()
        fo.close()
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name='bucket-name', key=fullname).put(Body=contents)
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                Params={'Bucket': 'bucket-name', 'Key': fullname},ExpiresIn=300
                )
        list_of_images.append({"imagepath":response})
        print(response)
        df=pd.DataFrame(list_of_images)
    df=json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))
    print(df)
    # return fullname
    return JsonResponse(df,safe=False)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to store the barcode, and not generate it "when necessary"?

Comment: yeah. I need to store the generated barcode file into s3 bucket.  as per my reqmnt.

Comment: It looks like `barcode.writer` doesn't support file-like objects for its `ImageWriter` objects, just filename. In other case you could use `io.BytesIO` object as an in-memory file without writing it to disk.